# Custom Woocommerce variable product price range for more than one active variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price, product-variations

I'm using this script, which I found on the Internet, to remove price range and display only minimum price for variable products in WooCommerce/WordPress in following syntax: **From US$ xxxx**

I'd like the script to do this same thing with exception when variable product has only one variation.
There is an automated cron (bash + SQL script) which removes products that are unavailable. Sometimes it leaves a variable product with only one variation, and listing this variation with a price stating "From US$ xxx" looks rediculous, as there is only one single variation).

How would you add a condition that applies this From US$ xxx to only variable products that have more than one variation. My primary goal is to use it on catalog/category/shop pages, as there is a already a snippet that removes price range from variable single product page. Thanks.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'bbloomer_variation_price_format_310', 10, 2 );
function bbloomer_variation_price_format_310( $price, $product ) {

// 1. Find the minimum regular and sale prices

$min_var_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
$min_var_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );

// 2. New $price

if ( $min_var_sale_price ) {
$price = sprintf( __( 'From %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $min_var_reg_price ) );
}

// 3. Return edited $price

return $price;
}

// Display Price For Variable Product With Same Variations Prices
add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', function ($value, $object = null, $variation = null) {
    if ($value['price_html'] == '') {
        $value['price_html'] = '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>';
    }
    return $value;
}, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting visible children in your 1st function will allow you to achieve that. Also I have revisited your 2nd function which should be named:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_variation_price_html', 20, 2 );
function custom_variation_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
    $visible_children = $product->get_visible_children();
    if( count($visible_children) <= 1 ) return $price_html; // Exit if only one variation

    $regular_price_min = $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
    $sale_price_min = $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );

    if ( $sale_price_min ) 
        $price_html = __( 'From', 'woocommerce' ).' '.wc_price( $regular_price_min );

    return $price_html;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_available_variation', 20, 3 ) ;
function custom_available_variation( $args, $product, $variation ) {
    if( $args['price_html'] == '' )
        $args['price_html'] = '<span class="price">' . $variation->get_price_html() . '</span>';
    
    return $args;
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or theme).

Tested and works.