# How can I remove price range for variable products with only one variation?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a furniture site built on wordpress and woocommerce. For consistency, I wanted to have variations for all bedframes, even if they only come in one size (king, queen, twin). However, variation products on woocommerce naturally have a price range describing the minimum price to maximum price between variations. If I only have one variation, it has a blank minimum price, and still has the hyphen and then the maximum price, as shown below, making it seem like it's negative. How can I remove the hyphen for products with one variation (including where all the other variations are disabled).

[image]

This site is khemlanimart.com

EDIT: I dont want it to just replace with the min price because when there is one variation, the min price is empty. If anything I wanted to it to be replaced with the max price in the case where there is only one variation and still keep the price range when there is multiple variations

Comment: I do apologize Loic. I will do better in the future. I’m just not familiar with php but that’s no excuse

Comment: Ok… I just updated my answer, there was a mistake on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated** *(replaced incorrect `$this` with `$product`)*.

Try the following, that should remove the price range for variable products with one variation:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'variable_products_with_one_variation', 10, 2 );
function variable_products_with_one_variation( $price_html, $product ) {
    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );
    
    if( count($prices['price']) == 1 ) {
        $active_price = end( $prices['price'] );
        $reg_price    = end( $prices['regular_price'] );
        
        if ( $this->is_on_sale() ) {
            $price = wc_format_sale_price( wc_price( $reg_price ), wc_price( $active_price ) );
        } else {
            $price = wc_price( $active_price );
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

It should work. Anyways if it doesn't work, [this is the right hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/02cf0dfaed5923513de0c88add597d1560c2cfd2/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L167) to be used.

Comment: Hmm. The code didn't work. I got this
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/functions.php:25 Stack trace: #0 . Trying to debug now. Thank you though and trying the link you mentioned

Comment: I tried your other code as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832078/custom-woocommerce-variable-product-price-range-for-more-than-one-active-variati
 and got: Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function ' custom_variation_price_html' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 287. Didnt seem to change anything.

Comment: Ahh, with $product instead of $this like you said, the error is gone, but the hyphen is still there for some reason.

Comment: @VikramKhemlani I have updated [Custom Woocommerce variable product price range for more than one active variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832078/custom-woocommerce-variable-product-price-range-for-more-than-one-active-variati/48837621#48837621) … That was simpy an additional white space.

Comment: @VikramKhemlani On my answer here, the hyphen is maybe on the formatted sale price,  but there is not anymore any price range…

Comment: Ah ok thank you! I'll see how to modify that! The hyphen is still there so trying to get rid of it.

Comment: The hyphen is still there in the regular price I mean, so working on that :)

Comment: I think it might be my theme, because no matter what I put, nothing in the price changes

Comment: This worked. Something was wrong with my plugin setup. Thanks!